# Connection problem to Github

Tags: git, github

When I try to evaluate a `Quelpa` expression that fetches a package from Github, it throws the following error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Command ’(env LC_ALL=C git clone https://github.com/ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el.git /Users/amaro/.emacs.d/quelpa/build/mac-classic-theme/)’ exited with non-zero status 128: Cloning into '/Users/amaro/.emacs.d/quelpa/build/mac-classic-theme'...\nfatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured\n")
  signal(error ("Command ’(env LC_ALL=C git clone https://github.com/ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el.git /Users/amaro/.emacs.d/quelpa/build/mac-classic-theme/)’ exited with non-zero status 128: Cloning into '/Users/amaro/.emacs.d/quelpa/build/mac-classic-theme'...\nfatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured\n"))
  error("Command '%s' exited with non-zero status %d: %s" ("env" "LC_ALL=C" "git" "clone" "https://github.com/ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el.git" "/Users/amaro/.emacs.d/quelpa/build/mac-classic-theme/") 128 "Cloning into '/Users/amaro/.emacs.d/quelpa/build/mac-classic-theme'...\nfatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured\n")
  quelpa-build--run-process(nil "git" "clone" "https://github.com/ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el.git" "/Users/amaro/.emacs.d/quelpa/build/mac-classic-theme/")
  quelpa-build--checkout-git(mac-classic-theme (:repo "ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el" :fetcher github :url "https://github.com/ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el.git") "/Users/amaro/.emacs.d/quelpa/build/mac-classic-theme/")
  quelpa-build--checkout-github(mac-classic-theme (:repo "ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el" :fetcher github) "/Users/amaro/.emacs.d/quelpa/build/mac-classic-theme/")
  quelpa-build-checkout(mac-classic-theme (:repo "ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el" :fetcher github) "/Users/amaro/.emacs.d/quelpa/build/mac-classic-theme")
  quelpa-checkout((mac-classic-theme :repo "ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el" :fetcher github) "/Users/amaro/.emacs.d/quelpa/build/mac-classic-theme")
  quelpa-build((mac-classic-theme :repo "ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el" :fetcher github))
  quelpa-package-install((mac-classic-theme :repo "ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el" :fetcher github))
  quelpa((mac-classic-theme :repo "ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el" :fetcher github))
  eval((quelpa '(mac-classic-theme :repo "ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el" :fetcher github)) nil)
  eval-expression((quelpa '(mac-classic-theme :repo "ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el" :fetcher github)) nil nil 127)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression (quelpa '(mac-classic-theme :repo "ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el" :fetcher github)) nil nil 127)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-expression)
```

Given `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured`, it seems the issue relates to Github authentication issue but on the same machine `ssh -T git@github.com` successfully authenticates.

Should I configure something on the Emacs side to make it work with Github?

Comment: It looks like your remote is set up over https rather than ssh, so the fact that you can authenticate over ssh isn't relevant. Try (re)creating the remote and using ssh.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10, thanks but the project is not mine, how do I set up a remote for other people's projects and make it uses ssh rather than https?

Comment: Your `:repo` is wrong. Try going to https://github.com/ahobson/mac-classic-theme.el. It 404's. You should use `ahobson/mac-classic-theme`.

Comment: @nega, you're right, my mistake there. Issue fixed, though the error msg was a little misleading

Comment: Great! Feel free to self-"answer and accept", as comments can disappear.